# Set Cookies in my browser application in android when browser starts

Tags: android, session-cookies, android-browser

I am developing an app for my understanding of the android browser and cookies.

I am using webview for that. I am storing cookies in file when user leaves application and I want to set them when next time user launches my browser, he will be navigated to his prev session for that I tried to use setcookie method from cookie manager but some how cookies are not set properly.

This is just a test app to understand the behavior. so I have not considered session security  yet.

is this the correct approach or can anybody suggest better way to achieve this.